# How to get all the preferred parents up to the root for a certain node in Contiki RPL classic?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I'm using Contiki 3.0 and I would like to find all the preferred parents up to the root for a certain node. For Example, if I have node 1 with preferred parent node 5, node 5 with preferred parent node 8 and node 8 connected directly to the root.
How can I find or print these preferred parents like this: 1-> 5 -> 8 -> root.
I'm using this code to get the preferred parent:
PRINT6ADDR(rpl_get_parent_ipaddr(dag->preferred_parent));

Many Thanks
Hanin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print this information on a node since RPL is a distance vector protocol, not a link state protocol. A network node does not have enough information to know the full routing path to the root node; it has just a local view of the network, limited to their immediate neighbors.

Comment: In this case how is RPL able to calculate end-to-end ETX. I mean How a node knows the total ETX path up to the root if the node does not know the full routing path.

Comment: @H.Almutairi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol